# Determining modifying statements from non-modifying in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

What is the most reliable way to determine what statements are "querying" versus "modifying"?  For example, `SELECT` versus `UPDATE / INSERT / CREATE`.

Parsing the statement myself seems the obvious first attempt, but I can't help but think that this would be a flaky solution.  Just looking for `SELECT` at the beginning doesn't work, as PRAGMA can also return results, and I'm sure there are a multitude of ways that strategy could fail.  Testing for zero rows returned from the cursor doesn't work either, as a SELECT can obviously return zero results.

I'm working with SQLite via the Python sqlite3 module.

Comment: If you just need to assert that a statement *cannot* modify data, then wrap it in a transaction and roll it back at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [sqlite3_changes](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) API call, which is also available from SQL using the [changes](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function.

As TokenMacGuy mentioned, you can rollback the transaction containing the statement that caused the changes; the `sqlite3_changes` function will let you know if that is necessary.

There is also the [update_hook](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html) callback if you need more fine grained information abouth the tables and rows affected.